# What do I need for remotely accessing my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop?

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, vncviewer

I am at a loss as to how to set up my machine for remote connection. Do I need to install a VNC server (which one?) or is Vino (installed by default) enough?

I opened Desktop Sharing Preferences dialogue and enabled it (checked first two, allow to connect and control). I tried to connect using RealVNC Chrome App, but it says

> The authentication mechanism requested cannot be provided by the computer.
>   VNC Viewer also fails with an error about encryption level.

By the way, eventually I am going to need to connect from a Windows 7 machine, but for now I just want to get it to work.

Comment: This might be helpful http://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-to-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely/592544

Answer (score 30):

This is a late reply but there is a way to use Vino without encryption which may benefit others.

install `dconf-tools`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

start `dconf-editor` from the command line and go to `org->gnome->desktop->remote-access`and toggle the `require-encryption` item to unchecked.

If desktop sharing was enabled prior to changing the setting, then execute the following from the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

If desktop sharing was not enabled prior to changing the setting, then enable desktop sharing.

Comment: Great. After upgrading from Debian 7 to 8 I was unable to remote view my pc. This solution actually worked. :) :)

Comment: Lame, disabling secure connections is pretty not-acceptable as an answer. Got me though this one time though.

Comment: Thanks so much! The easiest and most effective way to access in an office environment where external installations are blocked due to security!

Answer (score 6):

I've personally found that installing and using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) (although it actually works under a custom version of Wine) is the most straight-forward solution for remote access/control.

To install:

1. Download the official image from http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx (always get 32bit)
2. Open a console
3. Run command `cd ~/Downloads/`
4. Run command `sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb`
5. Follow whatever steps it needs you to take.

You do not need (or want) the 64bit package, as Ubuntu has a "multiarch" feature, allowing a 64bit OS to natively run 32bit programs.

Comment: Why go for the 32bit version if your computer is 64Bit?

Comment: Funny how a non-native solution works out-of-the-box while others that come bundled with Ubuntu doesn't. :-/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, at your Ubuntu machine you need to install VNC Server `sudo apt-get install x11vnc`. At your Windows 7 machine you need yo install VNC client, for example Tight VNC http://www.tightvnc.com/

Comment: What is Vino then?

Comment: @lfk Vino is the default VNC server in Ubuntu to share your existing desktop with other users.

Answer (score 4):

If you have "Server did not offer supported security type" error connection in window Vnc, follow the link below.
For Ubuntu 14.04 VNC

[Fix VNC Desktop Sharing](http://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/KB:Fix_VNC_Desktop_Sharing_on_Ubuntu_Desktop_14.04)

```
sudo apt-get -y install dconf-tools
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/require-encryption false   /usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable start
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not much fan of closed source products but best working and fastest is ["NoMachine"](https://www.nomachine.com/download/download&id=4). It outperforms TeamViewer & VNC easily (but not RDP, so 'xrdp' could be still an option!), especially on low networks. If your target machine is behind the internet, you will need connect them through a proxy or VPN server.

Download the deb file, and then run sudo dpkg -i nomachine_4.4.12_11_amd64.deb. It does all, no need to do extra steps except adjusting security (password). It uses linux users and comes with lots of toys too.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed it's an old post, but for those of us who don't like 3rd-party-tools and would like to use native applications, I've found this great solution for Ubuntu 14.04 users:
http://www.tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-04/