# Connect on Ubuntu server 16.04 from windows via remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-login

I am a newbie with Ubuntu and I am trying to connect to my Ubuntu 16.04 server from my windows machine via its default remote desktop connection. I was following the solution mentioned in this post: [Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-to-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)

Everything works until the login phase. There, in selecting the last option, like:

[image]

I can establish a connection, but shortly afterwards I get this:

[image]

Then the window is closed and I have to reenter the IP etc.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: your question relates to a post which advises you to use `sesman-Xvnc`, but you seem to be using `sesman-X11rdp` - why? and what is happening if you use `sesman-Xvnc`?

Comment: it has an error connecting with sesman-Xvnc, and I tried also the other ones to see if they worked, and sesman-X11rdp was the only one that had a successful connection

Comment: I have the exact same problem.
Anyone with an idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: the same here, my connection started and then stop and close the session