# Increase font size of putty

Tags: 16.04, putty

I am using putty for remote login in Linux in Ubuntu. The font size of terminal is very small. How can I increase it's font size.

Comment: Are you using Putty from Windows?

Comment: Both in Ubuntu and windows

Answer (score 14):

- Putty configuration
- Window
- Appearance
- Font Settings
- Font
- Change
- Size: pick the smallest one possible, which is 8 for me
- Go back to "Sessions", select a "saved session" and click "Save". Terrible interface design!

  - https://serverfault.com/questions/12295/how-to-make-putty-settings-persistent
  - https://serverfault.com/questions/52068/is-there-a-way-to-permanently-set-the-font-and-window-size-in-putty

I wish I could go even smaller a bit, but it is already a huge improvement.

Also consider using MobaXterm instead of Putty: [Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely/954989#954989) It is almost inevitable.

Tested on Putty 0.70, Windows 10 local, Ubuntu 16.04 remote.

Answer (score 2):

The setup is somewhat different if you using Putty on Ubuntu.

Go to **Fonts** under **Window**, and change the **Font used for ordinary text**. Usually it's set to a default font by the server.

[image]

Here, you can select a font you want and update the preferred font size.

[image]