# Hostname -I gives 2 IP addresses

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a windows PC and I want to use the windows PC to remotely connect to my Ubuntu PC. I need this because I have to use a projector that doesn't work on my Ubuntu PC.

I tried all the steps at [Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely).

Now when I do `hostname -I` on my Ubuntu PC:

I get two addresses:  `10.xxx.xxx.xx  172.xx.x.x`

I used both the addresses on my windows PC (Remote Desktop) to connect to my Ubuntu PC but none work: I get the message that either your PC is turned Off etc.

Please help as I have to present in some hours.

Comment: please tell us more about your networking configuration. None of those addresses are for real networks, I think. What is the address of your windows PC?

Comment: Technically, 172.xx.xx.xx could be a real IP, but I think assuming it's a private ip between 172.16.0.0 and 172.31.0.0 is a safe start. @MarkYisri

Comment: @MarkYisri the previous comment is correct. Also, My Ubuntu PC and my Windows PC rae connected on two different Wifi networks.