# How to get remote access from Windows to Ubuntu's laptop without additional networking devices?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, remote, remote-access

I have two laptops and I would like to know how (if possible) to get remote control over Ubuntu's desktop from Windows (preferably Windows 10), but without additional networking equipment, for example through ad-hoc network.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)

Comment: Purists would install OpenSSH on the Ubuntu computer and use PuTTY on the Windows computer, in order to establish a terminal session, command-line style.

Comment: Install any RDP software to use in remote. For example XRDP.

Comment: How would the two computers communicate with each other, but without networking equipment?

Comment: @Service Manager it is possible to connect two laptops using cable (point to point connection), so I suggested that may be there also way to do this wireless (through wi-fi or bluetooth)

Comment: It is possible to connect them to each other via an ad-hoc network, but I'm curious why you're foregoing a router/switch.

Comment: The fastest/cheapest way is by using Teamviewer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several programs to do this GUI side, but I recommend Synergy.

https://symless.com/synergy/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Another alternative for seeing the other screen is teamviewer.  Its not what most developers would use, but suitable to use another computer remotely or through network.

Comment: Synergy only allows the use of a single keyboard and mouse on multiple computers. The video is still tied to its respective monitor/computer.

Comment: Teamviewer then