# Access Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows 10 through XRDP (error - problem connecting)

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

I followed all the instructions from [this ticket](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely) to the letter, but I get an error in the Connection log :

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
tcp connected
security level is 2 (1 = none, 2 = standard)
password ok
sending share flag
receiving server init
error - problem connecting
```

I can't seem to find a solution for this even if this question matches many others.

*EDIT : Since I've got no answers, I managed to use TightVNC using [this procedure](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/remote-access-ubuntu-16-04/).*