# XRPD wont connect from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, xrdp

I want remote control my home PC from laptop.
They are connected to 1 router (PC with cable, Laptop wireless WiFi).

I have done instructions from this question ([Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)), but when i finish, I didn't got my PC screen.

Connection Log screen says:

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
```

And nothing more. I've wait for 5 minutes, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the same host (linux machine). Look at the IP - it's localhost (address of the machine from which you try to connect from). Try providing address of linux machine (try `ifconfig` on the linux machine).