# Remote desktop client to access Windows from Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, software-recommendation, rdp, client

I want to access a Windows machine on my LAN from Lubuntu 16.10. Looking for RDP client software for Lubuntu. Is there any?

Comment: maybe with link can help - but i think it for other way of what u want sorry:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely

Answer (score 2):

Yes, e.g. [Remote Desktop Viewer](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Vinagre). Although it is a Gnome application, it will work on Lubuntu. See this [help](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop) article at the Ubuntu wiki.

However, if you just want to access files from a Windows machine you will probably want [Samba](https://www.samba.org/). See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide) help article at help.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 0):

For the Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) on Lubuntu you can probably use **xrdp**

http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Xrdp,_installing

prefer VNC though as it's easier setup for windows and linux but xrdp should be able to connect with both.