# ubuntu windows remote connection

Tags: windows, remote-access

I have completed all steps given on "[Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)" .
Still my windows 8.1 system showing a dialog box title **Connection Log** after entering credentials of ubuntu 16.04 LTS system ends no where.
What should be done?

Comment: are you connecting in a local network or over internet?

Comment: @hunch I am trying to connect over Internet.