# Use Autologin functionality

Tags: 16.04, auto-login

I'm now able to access Ubuntu 14 LTS from Windows as described in [Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)

But how do I set autologin for any login?

As soon as it boots I want it to automatically login.

I want to use as described [in here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin) . For that I've installed `lightdm` and also run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (it simply does nothing actually). But still when I login I see the same `xfce` Window Manager. This file: `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` contains `lightdm`

Comment: @user68186 sorry I meant to say that I'm already able to access Remote Desktop. The remote root login was already enabled. The root password was too enabled. Any suggestion in which version I can access using Remote Desktop as well as use autologin in Linux of any flavour?

Comment: You shouldn't log into the root account for normal daily usage. Pick another user account and set the auto login there.

Comment: @heynnema any non root account is as well ok

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04) and it's autologging into root.