# How to add xRDP and XFCE4 o UFW rules?

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop, ufw, xrdp

I'm new here and I've just installed and configured xRDP and XFCE4 on my Ubuntu 16 server so I can Remote Desktop from my Windows PC. [Faizan Akram Dar](https://askubuntu.com/users/278703/faizan-akram-dar)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/592544/758136) worked perfectly!
Then I installed an open VPN server and followed the recommendations to activate the UFW firewall. And so the Remote Desktop no longer worked. I solved it by adding to the the UFW rules the whole IP range of my router's DHCP service and the 3389 port.

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.100
sudo ufw allow 3389
```

However, I was wondering if there is a way to set up a more restrictive rule for this purpose.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I don't think those rules do what you think they do.

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.100
```

allows connections to ANY port with ANY protocol FROM the single address 192.168.1.1 TO the single address 192.168.1.100 - unless your interface is actually configured on 192.168.1.100 and you have a client at 192.168.1.1 this will have no effect.

On the other hand,

```
sudo ufw allow 3389
```

will allow connections to port 3389 with ANY protocol from ANY remote address to ANY local interface.

Probably what you want is either

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3389
```

or (slightly more restrictive)

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 3389 proto tcp
```

which will allow any clients on the local CIDR subnet 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.254 to connect to the RDP port using TCP:

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24            
[ 2] 3389/tcp                   ALLOW IN    192.168.1.0/24
```