# How do I RDP to Ubuntu14 from Windows7xpro remotely AND see the native desktop(open apps, process, etc)?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access

[So I successfully installed an XRDP client using this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)

But the desktops are all like VM *desktop emulators* and don't show the real desktop. Odd that I can be logged in on both RDP and direct to the box and not see changes made to either location - or see previously open apps.

Looked at team viewer (too expensive) and looking at Logmein (We have that) --but/or-- is there a Free effective option to remoting in without having to install CygWin or anything windows side and just use windows remote desktop connection? (Corporate environment hard to get installs)

Can an RDP session in Ubuntu 14 allow direct login to the desktop from windows 7x64 pro?

I.e. when I RDP from windows at home to my computer in the office in windows - I see all the files I have open, where I left off, word is open, etc. have access to all active processes, etc…

Comment: Hi there, just a note to say that although I think I can be done with RDP, I have solved this problem in the past by using a VNC server to connect to desktop 0. You're correct that the normal behaviour of remote sessions is to give you a new session, not to log into the current desktop session. This reflects the philosophy of UNIX being a multi-user environemnt. There may be an option in your RDP server which will allow you to set the default desktop for new sessions. Hopefully someone more up-to-date comes along and can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks @jeremy- that is what I am looking for! Hopefully someone will answer and I will see more about accessing Desktop-0 : )