# Access Ubuntu 20.04 remotely from Windows 10 on the same computer

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, remote-access

I have installed both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on the same computer with dual boot option, and it works fine. Can I access Ubuntu remotely from the same computer after logging into Windows?

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely) about how to access Ubuntu remotely from Windows. If I follow these steps will I be able to access Ubuntu remotely on the same computer?

Comment: What do you need to do exactly?  You can't run both operating systems simultaneously in a dual boot configuration so you can't access a working version of Ubuntu from Windows, but of course you can access the file system, assuming that you have software installed in Windows that can read the file system you used for Ubuntu.

Comment: There used to be a program for Windows that let Windows read Linux files on dual boot systems, like Linux can read Windows files, but it has not been updated for years and caused problems.  Answer for your question for now is No for accessing Ubuntu, but if you have a NTFS data partition, Windows can read those files.

Answer (score 1):

You can only boot one operating system at a time in a dual boot setup. When Windows 10 is running in a Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot then Ubuntu is not running, and you can't access Ubuntu remotely from Windows if it is not currently running.