# Remote Ubuntu pc

Tags: remote-desktop, monitor, remote, remote-access, xrdp

I built a great ubuntu pc at my family house, but now moving to university dorms.
I can't take my pc with me because of space and electricity issues, but will take my monitor and laptop (that has lower performance).
I'd like to remotely use my pc (that's not connected to any monitor) from the dorms using my laptop - what's the best way doing so?
(Got dummy HDMI if that helps).
I tried xrdp - works but not so smooth.
Tried NoMachine - works, smoother but gives black screen when monitor is not connected (even though I plugged a dummy HDMI).
Open to any suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using? Newer release have build-in support for remote connection via RDP, just needs to be activated.

Comment: @noisefloor  Using the latest release. The RDP needs the pc to be physically signed in after every restart, and as I mentioned the headless xrdp doesn't supply good enough performance (and has different GUI). If there is a way to combine xrdp to sign in and than RDP to remote that could be a great solution, but I yet couldn't find a way for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I access Ubuntu from Windows remotely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely)