# How can I get a full desktop remotely?

Tags: server, remote-desktop

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop on my personal computer desktop. How can I get the same desktop experience on a server running Ubuntu Server remotely? I have tried things like VNC but it does not look the same. My hope is that I can be able to use it similarly to how I use RDP to connect to Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Ubuntu servers come only with command line interface. Servers don't have any GUI desktop. To use a server as a desktop remotely or otherwise, you will have to first install a desktop.

Comment: I am not sure about all the packages that need to be installed for that to happen. Previous attempts have left me with half a desktop.

Comment: Install a desktop on your server and then see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/724262/how-to-work-remotely-on-ubuntu-from-another-ubuntu-14-04-3?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

you can install remmina it is same as RDP.

https://remmina.org/how-to-install-remmina/

sudo snap install remmina

Comment: This is a client, not a server.

Comment: @NathanielFredericks - You said you want to connect to a server. This answer is one way to do so. If that's not what you intended to ask, then please edit your question to clarify.